# Add character :before <a> without including in anchor text

Tags: html, css

How can I add a character before a link without including it as part of the clickable anchor text?

HTML like:

```
<p>blah blah blah <a href="example.com">blah</a></p>
```

css like:

```
a:before {content: "foo ";}
```

Gives results like: blah blah blah [foo blah](http://example.com)

Desired result: blah blah blah foo [blah](http://example.com)

Comment: you could style it so it doesn't look clickable.  cursor: text; color: black;

Comment: Before and after are children of the element, so without some devilish hackery, I'm inclined to say no.

Comment: color: black;     cursor: text;     <- no longer looks clickable   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwEGvK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't separate them using pseudo as they are in the same DOM tree.

You may use a span and use content there:

```
<p>blah blah blah <span></span><a href="example.com">blah</a></p>

p span:before {content: "foo ";}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* CSS */
.link:before {content: "foo ";}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<p>
  blah blah blah
  <span class="link"><a href="example.com">blah</a></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `pointer-events: none` to make it non-clickable (make the click pass through):

```css
a:before {
  content: "nope ";
  pointer-events: none;
  
  /* to make it look "normal" */
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('click');">test</a>
```